# Karate ReferenceError: package is not defined

Tags: java, testing, karate, web-api-testing

I'm using java codes in karate feature file, refering github demo:

```
Background:
* url demoBaseUrl
* def JavaDemo = Java.type('com.intuit.karate.demo.util.JavaDemo')
```

I noticed that the feature file is in src/test/java, which defined as classpath in pom.xml. Meanwhile the util class is in src/main/java.

In my project I use similar structure

[image]

Following code is in the feature file with Class Reference:

```
    * def XMLValidator = Java.type(base.utility.XMLValidator)
    * def validator = new XMLValidator()
```

But I got an exception below:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "base" is not defined
```

Is it a classpath problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing the quotes (for a string argument to `Java.type()`

```
* def XMLValidator = Java.type('base.utility.XMLValidator')
```

Comment: Thanks, syntax checking is always a problem for there's only basic support from IDEs